# backup wordpress directory inside public_html with cPanel cron job

Tags: wordpress, cron, backup, cpanel

I have a wordpress in a directory inside public_html, inside a folder named 'my_wp'. How can I make a backup of this specific directory that contains WP files and databases with a cPanel cron job? Mi idea is to only backup this directory (not all public_html). And the best way to restore? Thanks!

Comment: Good day, Sebastian. Can you try to use Hosting cronjob tool?

Comment: Thanks for reply, what is that option?

Comment: Some hosting providers allow to backup only certain folder. But if your company dont let you, try this https://gist.github.com/pacmandv/fd5d334a535699c659363e8568d96978. There are options for mysql and files also

Comment: oh nice, thank you! I will try this